# Energy spectrum, mass spectrum, and mass gap

Tags: quantum-field-theory

In Arnold Neumaier's nice answer to this question:

[The energy spectrum in quantum field theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/3941/the-energy-spectrum-in-quantum-field-theory#)

it is remarked that

'If there is a mass gap (i.e., if no representation of tiny positive mass exists), the states can be restricted to their rest frame, where the spatial momentum vanishes; in this case the energy spectrum agrees with the mass spectrum...'

I wonder why it is that this holds only if there is a mass gap. That is, why could one not look at the mass spectrum as an energy spectrum in a rest frame in the case where there is no mass gap?

Comment: The lack of a mass gap goes in all intersting cases together with the existence of a massless particle. These don't have a rest frame. See, e.g., the sections

Answer (score 4):

A massless particle doesn't have a rest frame. Recall that in the rest frame, the momentum vector is given by

$$ p^\mu = (E,0,0,0)$$

and it must satisfy $p^2 = m^2$ where $m$ is the particle's mass. Now examine what happens for a state with $m^2 = 0$...

Comment: Does the lack of a mass gap actually imply a massless particle? Part of the reason I ask is in order to understand the Yang-Mills mass gap problem.

Answer (score 1):

The lack of a mass gap goes in all interesting cases together with the existence of a massless particle. These don't have a rest frame. See, e.g., the section ''What is the mass gap?'' in my theoretical physics FAQ at
http://arnold-neumaier.at/physfaq/physics-faq.html